# How do I move the lower section to the right of the upper section?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I move the lower section to the right of the upper section?
I use Bootstrap...
I'm new to Bootstrap.
I want to this view => http://prntscr.com/ua4e4p

```
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <img src="img/frame.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Product</label>
        <select required name="proje_aciliyet" class="form-control">
          <option>SWA-71</option>
          <option>QAZ-89</option>
          <option>Acelesi Yok</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group col-md-4 float-right">
        <label for="inputState">Urgent</label>
        <select required name="proje_aciliyet" class="form-control">
          <option>No</option>
          <option>Yes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you provide same code which shown in screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping two input in same below you have to wrap into one column.

Try this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/725x250/e031e0/fff" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group col-md-4 float-right">
        <label for="inputState">Product</label>
        <select required name="proje_aciliyet" class="form-control">
          <option>SWA-71</option>
          <option>QAZ-89</option>
          <option>Acelesi Yok</option>
        </select> 
     
        <label for="inputState">Urgent</label>
        <select required name="proje_aciliyet" class="form-control">
          <option>No</option>
          <option>Yes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: don't forget to accept answer if this help you. @BurakFırçasıgüzel